# Image Type Error: OpenCV Python

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, error-handling

I get an image type error when I run my code. I know HoughLinesP requires a grayscale image but when I try to convert the source image to grayscale I get the following error(1):

> error: (-215) depth == 0 || depth == 2 || depth == 5 in function cv::cvtColor

If I run HoughLinesP without converting to grayscale I get the following error(2):

> error: (-215) image.type() == (((0) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((1)-1) << 3)) in function cv::HoughLinesProbabilistic

I don't know what conversion I need to get rid of the error

This is the code for where the errors occur:

```
#extract largest component from image.
components, output, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(threshold_img, connectivity=4)
sizes = stats[:, -1]

max_label = 1
max_size = sizes[1]
for i in range(2, components):
    if sizes[i] > max_size:
        max_label = i
        max_size = sizes[i]
biggestComponent = np.zeros(output.shape)
biggestComponent[output == max_label] = 255
biggestComponent = biggestComponent - cv2.erode(biggestComponent, np.ones((5,5), np.uint8))
dilated = cv2.dilate(biggestComponent, np.ones((3,3), dtype=np.uint8))

#-------------------------ERROR(1)----------------------------#
dilated = cv2.cvtColor(dilated, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#obtaining corners using houghlines
def find_intersection(line1, line2):
    # extract points
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = line1[0]
    x3, y3, x4, y4 = line2[0]
    # compute determinant
    Px = ((x1*y2 - y1*x2)*(x3-x4) - (x1-x2)*(x3*y4 - y3*x4))/  \
        ((x1-x2)*(y3-y4) - (y1-y2)*(x3-x4))
    Py = ((x1*y2 - y1*x2)*(y3-y4) - (y1-y2)*(x3*y4 - y3*x4))/  \
        ((x1-x2)*(y3-y4) - (y1-y2)*(x3-x4))
    return Px, Py

def segment_lines(lines, delta):
    h_lines = []
    v_lines = []
    for line in lines:
        for x1, y1, x2, y2 in line:
            if abs(x2-x1) < delta: # x-values are near; line is vertical
                v_lines.append(line)
            elif abs(y2-y1) < delta: # y-values are near; line is horizontal
                h_lines.append(line)
    return h_lines, v_lines

def cluster_points(points, nclusters):
    criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10, 1.0)
    _, _, centers = cv2.kmeans(points, nclusters, None, criteria, 10, cv2.KMEANS_PP_CENTERS)
    return centers

#-------------------------ERROR(2)----------------------------#
# run the Hough transform
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(dilated, rho=1, theta=np.pi/180, threshold=100, maxLineGap=20, minLineLength=50)
```

Comment: The first error is returned because image shape has 3 components, Height Width and Channel, the third describing the number of color components. The 'image' you're creating does not have the third shape and hence cvtColor will not work on it. Try adding the 3rd component using np.expand_dims

Comment: @VaibhavMehrotra the dilated image I'm passing into cvtColor only has height and width when I print image.shape so why does HoughLinesP produce an error when the image is already grayscale?

Comment: @OcheGeorge check the datatype of your variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some basic understanding of images and their properties is required.

In OpenCV images are basically arrays. Before proceeding with any sort of conversion ensure if it is possible in the first place.

**How does one do that?**

1. Get to know about its properties like its shape (is it 2D or 3D). Check for the shape using the `shape` attribute.
2. Know about its datatype (`int` or `float`)
3. In order to convert it to a suitable datatype use `astype()` and pass in the datatype you want your array to be in.

Coming back to your question! (I actually ran your entire code to arrive at this conclusion)

#### Error 1:

> error: (-215) depth == 0 || depth == 2 || depth == 5 in function cv::cvtColor

This error occurs whenever the image you pass in has the wrong shape. In the line that causes this error `cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY` expects the image to be a 3D array but when you check it using `dilated.shape`, it returns a tuple of two values something like this `(558L, 796L)`, which is not a 3D array. You are passing in a 2D array where the function expects a 3D array. The result of `cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY` is a 2D array.

#### Error 2:

> error: (-215) image.type() == (((0) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((1)-1) << 3)) in function cv::HoughLinesProbabilistic

This error occurs due to the datatype of the array. The shape is correct but it expects an array of type `int`. `dilated` is a 2D array of type `float`.

So how do you change it? Change the datatype of the array using `astype`:

```
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(dilated.astype(np.uint8), rho=1, theta=np.pi/180, threshold=100, maxLineGap=20, minLineLength=50)
```