# EmguCV: What is the right variable to use for detector descriptors? Error:"OpenCV: > type=0"

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I'm trying to detect the keypoints and descriptors to match a template with another image.

I started to follow this [OpenCV tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/dff/tutorial_feature_homography.html), switched to ORB detector (as SURF algorithm is patented) but it's throwing an exception when I perform the `KnnMatch()`.

Here's my code:

```
Mat template = new Mat(templatePath, ImreadModes.Grayscale);
ORB orbDetector = new ORB(1000);
VectorOfKeyPoint keyPointTemplate = new VectorOfKeyPoint();
VectorOfKeyPoint keyPointImg = new VectorOfKeyPoint();
var descTemplate = new Mat();
var descImg = new Mat();
orbDetector.DetectAndCompute(template, new Mat(), keyPointTemplate, descTemplate, false);
orbDetector.DetectAndCompute(und, new Mat(), keyPointImg, descImg, false);
KdTreeIndexParams ip = new KdTreeIndexParams();
SearchParams sp = new SearchParams();
FlannBasedMatcher matcher = new FlannBasedMatcher(ip, sp);
VectorOfVectorOfDMatch knnMatches = new VectorOfVectorOfDMatch();
matcher.KnnMatch(descTemplate, descImg, knnMatches, 2); // exception: OpenCV: > type=0
```

The only example code I could find is [this official documentation](https://emgu.com/wiki/index.php/FAST_feature_detector_in_CSharp) that uses `FAST` but, as it was published 9 years ago, the code is outdated and when I tried to adapt to current EmguCV version gave only more issues.

I already tried changing `descTemplate` and `descImg` to VectorOf* but I had no luck with it.

Comment: Does the c++ code compile?  You should be using latest version.  What errors are you getting with latest version?

Comment: I cannot test the c++ code however yes, Im using EmguCV 4.5.5 (which wraps the c++ version of OpenCV 4.5.5) and the exception is the one mentioned in the code and title: `OpenCV: > type=0`

Comment: See the release notes and Dependencies : https://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Version_History?force_isolation=true#Emgu.CV-4.5.5  Make sure you are using CV 4.5.5

Comment: @jdweng I am. Directly from the nuget manager: 4.5.5.4823 for all the EmguCV related packages

Comment: See if this helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51182852/image-type-error-opencv-python?force_isolation=true

Comment: error says, that `KdTreeIndexParams` does not work with ORB descriptors (which have type==0, uchar) LSHIndex should work with those

Comment: @berak That was it, thank you. I took that `KdTreeIndexParams` from a C# tutorial with ORB indeed so I didn't double checked tbh. Thanks again for the answer, saved my afternoon.

Comment: @jdweng berak's answer solved the issue, thank you for the help and suggestions